# Django - how to create field as dropdown list from database table values and then post back to database

Tags: python, html, django, forms

This is being posted by a newbie who has been working on these 2 problems for over a week straight, with no results, and now am seeking help from the professionals on how to accomplish the following.

I have 2 pages.  The first page provides a search for an ASSIGNMENTS.ID.  Then the value is passed to a second page where the data for the ASSIGNMENTS is displayed. Below that all of the PRODUCTS linked to the ASSIGNMENTS.ID, as fk, are displayed in a table.  This works great.

*(PROBLEM #1 requesting help with:)* I would like to make the PRODUCTS.STATUS_CODE field on page 2 as a dropdown list of values from the data in the table.

This would allow the user to change the value of the PRODUCT.STATUS_CODE, by selecting another value from the dropdown list.

*(PROBLEM #2 requesting help with:)* After the PRODUCT.STATUS_CODE value change, how do I code to submit the page with changed STATUS_CODE value to be saved in the database.

NOTE:  The page 1 relates to the 'cancel_form_view' and the 'cancel_form.html'

The page 2 relates to the 'cancel_result_view' and the 'cancel_results.html'

Here are the code in Django files.

**MODELS.PY**

```
from django.db import models

class Assignments(models.Model):
    id = models.DecimalField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True, max_digits=9, decimal_places=0)
    name = models.CharField(db_column='NAME', unique=True, max_length=40)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = 'name',
        db_table = 'ASSIGNMENTS'

class Products(models.Model):
    id = models.DecimalField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True, max_digits=11, decimal_places=0)
    name = models.CharField(db_column='NAME', max_length=80)
    status_code = models.ForeignKey('ProductStatus', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='STATUS_CODE')
    assignment = models.ForeignKey(Assignments, models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='productsfor_assignment', db_column='ASSIGNMENT_ID', blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = 'name',
        db_table = 'PRODUCTS'

class ProductStatus(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(db_column='CODE', primary_key=True, max_length=10)
    description = models.CharField(db_column='DESCRIPTION', unique=True, max_length=80, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.code

    class Meta:
        ordering = 'code',
        db_table = 'PRODUCT_STATUS'
```

**VIEWS.PY**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Assignments, Products

def cancel_form_view(request):
    return render(request, 'assignments/cancel_form.html')

def cancel_result_view(request):
    q = request.GET.get('q', None)
    if q:
        assignments_qs = Assignments.objects.filter(id__icontains=q) \
            .prefetch_related('productsfor_assignment')
        context_data = {'assignments': assignments_qs}
        return render(request, 'assignments/cancel_results.html', context_data)
    else:
        # if the query is empty, render the 'cancel_form.html' template again.
        # display an error message in that template.  So, pass a template variable.
        # 'cancel_form.html' will check for the 'error' variable
        return render(request, 'assignments/cancel_form.html', {'error': True})
```

**TEMPLATES**

*CANCEL_FORM.HTML*

```
{% extends "base2.html" %}

{% block content %}

<p> CANCEL PRODUCT </p>

<p> Search for the Assignment. </p>

<br><br>
    {% if error %}
        <p style="color: red;">Please submit a search term.</p>
    {% endif %}
    <form action="/cancel-result/" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Enter ID here ...">
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

*CANCEL_RESULTS.HTML*

```
{% extends "base2.html" %}

{% block content %}

<h3> ASSIGNMENT to CANCEL product from</h3>

{% if assignments %}
    <ul>
        {% for assignment in assignments %}
        <li><label><b>Assignment ID:</b></label> {{ assignment.id }}</li>
        <li><label><b>Name:</b></label>{{ assignment.name }}</li>
    </ul>
            {% if assignment.productsfor_assignment.exists %}
            <h3>PRODUCTS</h3>the 
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Prod_ID</th>
                        <th>Status_Code</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                {% for product in assignment.productsfor_assignment.all %}
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>{{ product.id }}</b></td>
                        <td>{{ product.status_code }}</td>
                        <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                {% endfor %}

            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <p>No assignments matched your search criteria.</p>
{% endif %}

{% endblock content %}
```

**URLS.PY**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'assignments'

urlpatterns = [
    path('cancel-form/', views.cancel_form_view, name='Cancel product'),
    path('cancel-result/', views.cancel_result_view),
]
```

Comment: Maybe you want to look at django modelforms? You could just load the form with the instance given, display it and on submit use the form.save() method to reflect the changes made by user to your database?
Its not clear for me yet, where exactly your problem is, since you did not provide any error etc.

Comment: @erroinpersona Thank you for making the suggestion of modelforms.  Could you please explain 'load the form with the instance given, display it ....'  What does 'load the instance given' mean?  How would 'display it...' be done in the modelform?  Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Hey! You can read pretty much everything about modelform here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/ If you have questions after reading it, just ask :)

Comment: If it is confusing about what I am looking for help with, please see in the original post the italicized sentence with PROBLEM  #1 and PROBLEM #2 in them.  I hope someone is able to help.  Much appreciated for any guidance.  Thank you.